# Where I must handle Exception in php

Tags: php, exception

I'm wondering about in which level I must handle the `exception` 
for example

If I have a class that will handle the user object operations  and a `controller` to handle user routes actions

```
Class User
{
    function setUserName($name){
       //implementing the update process 
     } 

 }

Class UserController
{

 function updateUser($request){

   $user= new User()

   $user->setUserName($request['name']);
   }

}
```

If The update process may throw an exception ,What is the best practice to handle it? in user controller or user class and why ?

Comment: most of the time, you have to handle the error into your controller because your model does not necessarily know the context of the error (does the call comes from a web controller ? a cli command ? a unit test ? a service ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a normal try catch block :

```
function updateUser($request){

    // trigger exception 

    try {
        $user= new User()

        $user->setUserName($request['name']);
    }

    //catch exception
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use try and catch either  User class or Controller class ,I'm just asking about the best practice to do it

Comment: If you are calling the method at multiple places then using it in the controller class is feasible as the code becomes less redundant if you do so.